# Run tests with js wdio test runner via WebStorm IDE

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm trying to build a test framework using ***mocha + webdriver.io***.
I've chosen **wdio test runner** and all tests are running good via **CLI** but I want to configure **WebStorm** IDE to run single test in debug mode and can't understand how to do it.

As I understood there is no WebStorm support for this directly and I need to configure default Node.js run with valid parameters in order to trigger wdio runner with my test case.

[image: WebStorm config window]

Answer (score 1):

The next config is working for me (wdio+jasmine)

[image: screenshot is here]

Answer (score 0):

Check https://alippai.github.io/ for a brief guide. It's running the tests with the *mocha* executable instead of the default *wdio*.

Comment: Do you have an updated link for this? I get a DNS error. Perhaps it's best to put the content directly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `npm` type run config, assuming the wdio client is installed

in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js",
}
```

So then you can do `npm run wdio` on the command line to save remembering all the parameters.

Then you can setup a run/debug which just calls this. So instead of the Node.js format OP suggests, pick new `npm` and most of the fields are prefilled.

```
Name: "run my wdio tests or whatever"
package.json:  path/to/your/project/package.json
Command: `run`
Scripts: `wdio`
Node interpreter:  Project (whatever node your project is using)
Package Manager: Project (whatever npm your project is using)
```

I find the npm scripts is a good "long term memory" of all the ancillary command-lines a project will need. It can saves writing external documentation or bash scripts etc. for simple commands. So then it makes sense to run those from the run/debug as they will inherit any changes and keep in-IDE testing in sync with command-line (or CI/CD).